# Protected Sheet, Cell locked, won't accept VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a protected sheet WITH NO PASSWORD, cell D6 Locked. VBA code for that cell won't run.

I have read some posts here. This came as a solution to a similar problem. Not sure how to use it or where to put it. As stated I don't have a password on it.

```
Worksheets("Loading").Protect Password:=****, UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler '<--| be sure to catch any error and enable events handling back

Select Case Target.Address

    Case "$D$4"
       'Recalculate Downpayment D5 if Purchase Price is changed

       range("D5").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B5").Value) / 100
       Debug.Print "New value for D5 Downpayment "; range("D5").Value
       range("D6").Value = (range("D4").Value - range("D5").Value) ' This cell won't activate when locked and sheet protected
       Debug.Print "D6 New Mortgage " & range("D6").Value
```

[image: Cells]

Comment: If your sheet is protected (whether or not there's a password makes no real difference here) and the cell is locked then you will need to unprotect before making any changes from code, unless you protected in VBA using the `UserInterfaceOnly` argument.

Comment: am not sure that I explained correctly what I want. I want the field D6 locked because it isn't a field that the user should enter anything into. My vba code fills it in from the other cell entries. The problem is, that once I protect the page and then give it to the user the calculations don't autopopulate into D6. It stays at $0. I actually don't know why I should protect the sheet at all Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a worksheet change event that may change the value of cell D6.  To change the value of D6, if the cell is locked, then VBA needs to have it unprotected first. Now that you are saying you want D6 to be always protected, do this:

```
 Case "$D$4"
    'unprotect sheet
    Worksheets("Loading").Unprotect

   'Recalculate Downpayment D5 if Purchase Price is changed

   range("D5").Value = (range("D4").Value * range("B5").Value) / 100
   Debug.Print "New value for D5 Downpayment "; range("D5").Value
   range("D6").Value = (range("D4").Value - range("D5").Value) 
   Debug.Print "D6 New Mortgage " & range("D6").Value

  'protect the sheet back
   Worksheets("Loading").Protect
```

Please hit the check mark if this answered your question.

Comment: I don't know if what you wrote is for me. Where do you place that code? in a Module? I am not sure that I explained correctly what I want. I want the field D6 locked because it isn't a field that the user should enter anything into. My vba code fills it in from the other cell entries. The problem is, that once I protect the page and then give it to the user the calculations don't autopopulate into D6. It stays at $0. I actually don't know why I should protect the sheet at all.

Comment: ok, I edited the answer. KEEP IN MIND that you have to make sure cell D6 is locked. To do that right click on cell D6 > Format Cell > Protection and checkmark should be there for Locked. To do this, your sheet must be unprotected

Comment: If the sheet being updated is "Loading" then you can use (e.g.) `Me.Unprotect` instead of hard-coding in the sheet name.  In a Worksheet code module, `Me` refers to the associated worksheet.

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams. I used Me.Protect/Unprotect. It worked perfectly. Now I don't have to leave it unlock and trust the user not to enter anything. Very useful tidbit of code for me. Just new to this. Bit off a big chunk to chew and finally got the worksheets done. Thank you.